# How to do simple Plane Sweep triangulation?

Tags: opencv, 3d, triangulation

I have two cameras Cam1 and Cam2. They took two images of a static scene. I know the (identical) intrinsics K of both cameras and their translation and rotation in some common coordinate system.

If I do a plane sweep as illustrated below, how can I find the (x,y) position of p2 in the second image?

[image: plane sweeE]

Extra question: is there a way to let OpenCV calculate p2, given the information above? (I’m not interested in rectifying the images etc., I’d just like to get the color information of p2 given p1 and a depth zd)

Thank you.